# Rails: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AlbumsController#create Couldn't find User without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm currently receiving an error in my controller on submitting a form for creating an album. This is my first project and I am pretty shaky on controllers and what params to put and what to set the instance variables as... please help!!

on submission of my new.html.erb form, I receive

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AlbumsController#create

Couldn't find User without an ID

here is my albums_controller

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @albums = Albums.all

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @albums }
      end
    end

    def show
      @albums = Album.all
      @album = Album.find(params[:id])
      @photo = Photo.new
    end

    def update
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @user.album = Album.new(params[:album])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.album.save
          format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end 
    end

    def new
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @album = Album.new
    end

    def destroy
    end


end
```

here is the form I'm submitting

```
<%= form_for (@album), :html => { :id => "uploadform", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>


<%= f.label :description %>
<%= f.text_area :description %>

<br>

<%=f.submit %>
```

Let me know if you need any more files.

Comment: The very first line of your `create` action is trying to find a `User` based on the `user_id` request parameter. But I don't see any mention of `user_id` in your form.

Comment: hey jdoe. where would i be putting a reference to user_id in my form?

Answer (score 1):

In your `create`method you're trying to fetch a user from the database, based on `params[:user_id]`, and params doesn't contain any `user_id`.
In this case I believe that it should come from the URL

So one solution if an album belongs to the user would be to set your routes like that :

```
resources :users do
  resources :albums
end
```

Then you'll have to tell your form that the album is nested under a user byt explicitly giving the url. `user_albums_path` matches `/users/:user_id/albums(.:format)`

```
<%= form_for (@album), url: user_albums_path :html => { :id => "uploadform", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>


<%= f.label :description %>
<%= f.text_area :description %>

<br>

<%=f.submit %>
```

The your create method you receive the user_id it need in the params.

Let me know if'm not clear enough or if you need more explanations

You should use the build method defined [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)

```
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @user.album = Album.new(params[:album])
```

to create the album, you should

```
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @user.albums.build params[:album])
```

this will automatically set the user_id attribute of the album to @user.id, you won't have anything to do

so your create method should be

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build params[:album]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @album.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album} # I don't know what this location is 
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: hi pjam!! what you said about the url was what I needed, since it also helped change the url to include the user_id. however, I'm still receiving an error for my controllers... I'm pretty sure something is also wrong with my controller since I have no idea what I typed in there. Are my instance variables defined incorrectly?

Comment: Hum i'll check again, what is the error you're getting ? still the same ?

Comment: When creating the new album, you should use the albums.build method (more explanations here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)
`@user.albums.build params[:album]`

Comment: I also never used a `redirect_to model_instance` like you did, you should probably try `redirect_to user_path`instead

Comment: ok i'll change it. can you explain what the `url: user_albums_path` attribute actually does?

Comment: and for the comment you made about `@user.albums.build params[:album]`, would @user be set to `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`? and set what you said equal to @album (so it would be `@album = @user.albums.build params[:album]

Comment: It'll set the `action` attribute of your form. So imagine you're on the form of the user with 3. It'll be /users/3/albums
As you can see when typing `rake routes`, this routes is interpreted as /users/:user_id/albums(.:format), so the params[:user_id] will have the value 3.

Comment: I'm asking if the second half should be `@album = @user.albums.build(params[:album])` with the "@album = " or without it.

Comment: also... it doesn't seem to be saving my albums inside the user... whenever I try to print out the values of the albums in my views they are always empty. would that be an issue with my controller?

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. I checked my terminal and I think I found the reason why my @user.albums.count is staying 0. It keeps processing my form submission as a GET request... could this be because of the `url: user_albums_path` you mentioned? wouldn't it be `url: new_user_album_path` since I want to post? however it give s me the error `No route matches [POST] "/users/13/albums/new"` when i change it...

Comment: No it should not be `new_user_album_path`, it has to be `user_albums_path`, otherwise it won't call the create method.
The create method is called on a POST on `/users/:user_id/albums`, `/users/:user_id/albums/new` is only to display the album form

Comment: hey pjam, I've made a new thread for my other problem in case you want to see how my issue is solved or still have time to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680561/rails-form-submission-isnt-properly-creating-attributes